# How to trigger a Dispose of the ViewModel

Tags: wpf

My ViewModel implements IDisposable, but it looks like the the View (System.Windows.Window) does not.  So how do I ensure that the VM gets disposed in a timely fashion?

Comment: Do you have unmanaged resources that you need to deal with in your ViewModel? If not, you don't need to do anything in Dispose method and shouldn't really care when when the GC comes along and cleans up your VM and all of it's resources.

Comment: Not sure I understand the comment.  Of course I have resources that implement IDisposable. (Managed or not, does it matter?)  Therefore I need to dispose of them in a timely fashion --- hence the question.

Comment: The purpose of IDisposable is to release unmanaged resources. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx gives a more complete description. You cannot use IDisposable to release managed objects from memory. That is only done by the Garbage collector. If you have ***unmanaged resources***, then follow **JaredPar's answer**. If not, do nothing and don't worry about managed objects.

Comment: @Dave, you're Quite right.
My ViewModel greases the skids between the view and a network socket.  The socket should be disposed, and sometime before the GC cleans up the View Model.

I think the point about Unmanaged / Managed is at least somewhat symantics.  I would rather explain to my devlopers that if the thing you're using is Disposable, then so are you. (or words to such effect)

As a consumer of an IDisposable, I shouldn't care why the Dispose method should be called? (insert Tennyson quote here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on a bit on your scenario but the simplest way is to simply attach to the `Window::Close` event and Dispose of your view model at that time.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion if you have a window that you Open()/Close() many times?

Comment: > "Do you have any other suggestion if you have a window that you Open()/Close() many times?" 

I guess you create a new VewModel when you Open a window.